# Is it possible to to execute javascript code in a SPA that has already been built and delivered to the browser via C# controllers in ASP.NET CORE?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I am a front-end javascript developer. I am working with an ASP.Net developer who is building service end points for my SPA. He is trying to avoid using singal-r, but we need to know about events that are happening on the backend. I've been asked to research the following...

If a web application (ANGULAR SPA) is being hosted in asp.net core, is it possible for the C# controllers to execute javascript in the SPA after it has been delivered to the browser? If this is possible it would violate everything I know about the web world. Normally the SPA would have to communicate via http or websockets. However, I need to know if there is some type of technology that has been developed with ASP.net core which allows the execution of javascript code after browser delivery, or if there is a way outside of the standard http or websockets methods to know about events that happen in the backend, from the SPA.

Comment: Javascript's `eval()` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)) should allow you to execute any Javascript code, which you could e.g. retrieve from your ASP.Net backend via an asynchronous call. But SignalR is a much cleaner approach.

Comment: Thanks. But what I'm really looking for is a way to know about events that are occurring server side. Is SignalR the only way to do this?

Comment: If you want the backend to initiate the connection, SignalR is the best approach, yes. If the action is initiated by the frontend, then you'd have to devise a _polling_ system, whereas SignalR is a _pubsub_ system. (**Also**, your comment asks a completely different question than your question title. Note the difference, because you're close to making this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))